# xm vncviewer oad1 fails

Tags: linux, vnc

i am unable to use

```
[root@hoodad0n1 ~]# xm list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  3931    20     r----- 7062642.1
oad1                                         1 65539     8     r----- 33309460.3

[root@md01 ~]# xm vncviewer oad1 
invoking  vncviewer 0.0.0.0:0
Error: external vncviewer missing or not in the path
Exiting
[root@md01 ~]#
```

i get an error saying

```
Error: external vncviewer missing or not in the path
Exiting
```

i am very new to this any help would be apprciated.

i want to be able to vnc using the command `xm vncviewer oad1`
but unable to

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have updated the question..